# How to show another view controller first (before GameViewController.swift)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2

I am working on a SpriteKit Game and put all the logic so far in GameScene.swift. 
Out of the box, the Xcode template for a SpriteKit game is set up in a way, that GameViewController is displaying GameScene.swift (and the sks file) first.

What I want to do now is to add different screen (like, e.g. a main menu) that gets displayed first, before the game shows the GameScene.swift.
I feel a bit lost, maybe I do not have a clear view, but I do not know how to achieve this.

Can anyone give me a helping hand on this?

Comment: Simply make another scene file called for example MenuScene, GameViewController call MenuScene, MenuScene will call GameScene

Answer (score 3):

create a new view controller file like so

import UIKit

```
class NewViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let rect = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100)
        let testview = UIView(frame: rect)
        testview.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        view.addSubview(testview)
    }
}
```

in your AppDelegate set this view controller to be the root view controller

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        let newViewController = NewViewController()
        window?.rootViewController = newViewController
        return true
    }
```

you should see a red square now when you launch the game.   now its your job to make your menu on this new view controller and link this one to your original view controller.